# Typescript - custom loader for importing types

Tags: typescript

I have an idea I want to explore with Typescript, but not entirely sure if this is possible.

Say if I wanted to host types somewhere on a CDN, and a user can import them like this:

```js
import type { Article } from 'https://my-cdn.example/types/article';
```

Is there a way to configure Typescript and define a custom loader for this? For example, something that intercepts modules with a pattern like:

```
https://*
```

or

```
https://my-cdn.example/*
```

Given that ESM and Javascript can load modules from arbitrary URIs, I was curious if something like this is possible with types as well.

Comment: Along with a loader, it might also be fun to have an IDE plugin which would statically analyze the type from a URL (not sure if it exists) for getting auto-completion.

Comment: @vighnesh153 yeah that's more or less what I'm after =)